# Can a micro-SD card contain some encrypted and some unencrypted files?

Tags: encryption, sd-card

I recently upgraded from Samsung GS5 to GS7 edge.  I was encrypting the SD card in the old phone.  I believe that it was decrpyted when I removed it, because it was on and running, and I unmounted it from the settings menu.

However, several times I have restarted the GS7, entered my decryption pin, and then gotten a message that it cannot decrypt the storage because it was encrypted on another device.  Strange, but then I have been able to open folders and files (photos) stored on the card, right away, and without taking any further action or seeing any further message about decryption.

Is it possible that there could be a partitioned space on the SD card that is still encrypted, hiding files from me?  Or is this just a weird bug?  I would like to know before I return or sell the old phone, in case I still need to do anything with it.

Comment: Your question is out of scope here at Superuser

Comment: Please read the tags **before** posting your question.